# Cron job in google application engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I wrote a Python program to post things to the Internet.there is a function called send(x),with x is the xth record of my post list.I want to call the functions like send(0), send(1),....,with a rate about 5 min/post.How can I implement this task by using the cron configuration? Or task queue?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might consider using [`deferred.defer`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) here.

```
def send_wrapper(value):
    send(value)
    deferred.defer(send_wrapper, value + 1, _countdown=5*60)
```

Now you just need to manage to call this method once (e.g. from a handler) and it will call `send` every 5 minutes with an incremented value.  Underneath it all, this uses the TaskQueue API and pickling to provide a really easy interface for deferred tasks.  Neat.

Of course, calling this forever seems a bit strange but it wouldn't be too hard to add logic to terminate the sequence of deferred calls.

---

Your other option is to keep the value in the datastore and use cron... It's a bit more work (and requires a `db.Model` or `ndb.Model` that would really only be used for a single entity), but at the end of the day, it's still probably not that hard to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You need both. First you can add something like this to your cron.yaml file:

- description: task description here
  url: /tasks/send-updates
  schedule: every 15 minutes

Then in your router.py you'll need something like

webapp2.Route('/tasks/send-updates',
              'handlers.tasks.task_manager.SendUpdates'),

Finally, you have to implement your new handler (SendUpdates) in handlers/tasks/task_manager.py.

I advice to study the documentation given in [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron